# Androidのバックキーからの制御

Tags: android, monaca

Androidのハードウェアキーであるバックキーが押されたら、ダイアログを表示しアプリを終了させたいのですが、以下のコードでやっても正常に動作しません。

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);

  function onBackPressed()
  {
    confirmExit();
  }

  function confirmCallback(id)
  {
    if(1 == id)
    {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
  }
  function confirmExit()
  {
    navigator.notification.confirm("アプリケーションを終了しますか？", confirmCallback, "終了メニュー", "終了,キャンセル")
  }
```

アプリケーションを終了しますか？というダイアログは確かに出るのですが、終了を選択する前にアプリが終わってしまいます。
再度アプリを起動させると必要なjsファイルなどが読み込まれていない状態です。
※AngularJSで動作せてていますが、変数が変わらない為そう判断しています

```
document.addEventListener(
    "deviceready",
    function()
    {
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);
    }
    ,false
  );
```

上記のようなソースではそもそもダイアログも表示されません。

notification、exitappなどのプラグインはインストールしています

何か解決策ありましたら、お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでbackKeyの動作を無効化すればよいのではないでしょうか。

```
  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    // バックボタンが押されたときの処理
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      Log.d("dispatchKeyEvent", "バックボタン押された");

      // trueを返すことでbackKeyの動作を無効化
      return true;
    }

    // バックボタンじゃなかったら通常の動作をする
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
  }
```